# Submit button is not getting enabled in iPhones when each input field is linked to OnKeyUp event

Tags: node.js, iphone, selenium-webdriver

Submit button should be enabled when we enter the 4 MFA digits in a **modal dialog.** The developer code is checked on each OnKeyUp event of the inputs.

Note: This is working fine when entering the code on a Entercode page. The issue comes up only when the enter code happens inside a modal dialog

Issue in iPhones (when automated - Jest+Typescript+Selenium+BrowserStack):

1.Selenium sendKeys() is working to enter the keys inside the modal dialog input fields but the submit button is not getting enabled. It seems like the keys are sent but the key up event is not triggered.

2. Selenium element.click() followed by actions().sendKeys() - working on iPads but not on iPhones. I don't see the click() happening on the inputfield in the modal dialog

Is there an alternative approach that would help resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.